# Using powershell to sync files from one directory to a directory with a similar name but different dir structure

Tags: arrays, powershell, variables, robocopy

So I have two separate servers and I need to sync directories that have the same name, BUT are in a different directory structure.

For example one server it's `\\calafs01\GFX_Drop\x\*`

x is any directory in the GFX_Drop and I'm looking to copying all it's subfolders & their contents (modifications and new files only only)

the other server is `\\calamedia\edit\y\x\*`

y is an organizational category that our users use.

I need to copy anything that lands in x on calafs01 to calamedia, however because of y it's making it very difficult.

I can easily enough create an array with all of x's values:

```
$Projects = Get-ChildItem \\calafs01\GFX_Drop | %{$_.name}
```

but the issue is then having the script find directory x in whichever y directory it's in on calamedia to copy to.

Assuming to use robocopy once I can figure out how to do this...

Thanks in advance

**EDIT per NAS's answer:**

So I'm dumb and realized there's another directory AFTER x in calamedia, but it's ALWAYS called GFX, so the destination path is actually `\\calamedia\edit\y\x\GFX\*`

Assuming that would be a simple add... so took your script and did this:

```
$get_y = Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path \\calamedia\edit | Get-ChildItem -Directory     # get all dirs one level deeper

    Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path \\calafs01\GFX_Drop\ | ForEach-Object {              # get all folders 'x'
        $dest_y = $get_y | Where-Object -Property Name -eq $_.Name       # match folder names
        if ($dest_y) {
            Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Recurse -Destination "$dest_y.Parent.FullName/GFX" -Force -WhatIf
            # or robocopy if you need to copy modified/new files only
        }
    }
```

Basically just added the `/GFX` to the end of `$dest_y.Parent.FullName` (with quotes), figured this would work, but it now gets tripped up on the destination.  Do I have a syntax error expanding the directory?

**EDIT 2:**

Got it.

```
PS C:\Users\chris.slagel> $get_y = Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path \\calamedia\edit | Get-ChildItem -Directory     # get all dirs one level deeper

Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path \\calafs01\GFX_Drop\ | ForEach-Object {              # get all folders 'x'
    $dest_y = $get_y | Where-Object -Property Name -eq $_.Name       # match folder names
    if ($dest_y) {
        Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Recurse -Destination "$($dest_y.Parent.FullName)\GFX" -Force -WhatIf
        # or robocopy if you need to copy modified/new files only
    }
}
What if: Performing the operation "Copy Directory" on target "Item: \\calafs01\GFX_Drop\This Is A Test Destination: \\calamedia\edit\Theatrical\GFX".
What if: Performing the operation "Copy Directory" on target "Item: \\calafs01\GFX_Drop\This Is A Test - Copy Destination: \\calamedia\edit\Gaming\GFX".
What if: Performing the operation "Copy Directory" on target "Item: \\calafs01\GFX_Drop\This Is A Test - Copy (2) Destination: \\calamedia\edit\Home Entertainment\GFX".
What if: Performing the operation "Copy Directory" on target "Item: \\calafs01\GFX_Drop\This Is A Test - Copy (3) Destination: \\calamedia\edit\Home Entertainment\GFX".
What if: Performing the operation "Copy Directory" on target "Item: \\calafs01\GFX_Drop\This Is A Test - Copy (4) Destination: \\calamedia\edit\TV & Streaming\GFX".
What if: Performing the operation "Copy Directory" on target "Item: \\calafs01\GFX_Drop\This Is A Test - Copy (5) Destination: \\calamedia\edit\VR\GFX".
```

Looks like it's correctly finding the category folders, but it's missing the x part (the project names, in this case all the "This is a test" folders)

For example the first destination should be `\\calamedia\edit\Theatrical\This Is A Test\GFX`

Comment: Can folder x on the target server always be found one level deeper (is there only one folder (y) between 'calamedia\' en 'x')?

Comment: Yes, there is always just ONE y folder.

Comment: Use `"$($dest_y.Parent.FullName)\GFX"` to expand within quotes + backslash `\\`

Comment: You won't need the `Parent` in your modified question, that's only needed to merge/overwrite (existing destination) folders which is not necessary as you have `GFX` in between now.

Comment: Check my comment above on improving your Edit2

Answer (score 0):

```
$get_y = Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path \\calamedia\ | Get-ChildItem -Directory     # get all dirs one level deeper

Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path \\calafs01\GFX_Drop\ | ForEach-Object {              # get all folders 'x'
    $dest_y = $get_y | Where-Object -Property Name -eq $_.Name       # match folder names
    if ($dest_y) {
        Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Recurse -Destination $dest_y.Parent.FullName -Force -WhatIf
        # or robocopy if you need to copy modified/new files only
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot something haha.  Modified the question in response to your answer.